# Encrypt assertion SAML response

Tags: encryption, response, saml, keycloak

I'm working with a customer who acts as a IdP(keycloak), so I'm the SP. The problem is with the assertion encryption, the process should be(atleast I think it should work in this way):

- He encrypts the assertion with a symmetric key.
- The symmetric key is encrypted with my public key attached in the public certificate. ( SP )

But according with the keycloak doc  ( https://www.keycloak.org/docs/2.5/server_admin/topics/clients/client-saml.html ) :

> Encrypt assertions in SAML documents with the realm’s private key. The AES algorithm is used with a key size of 128 bits.

The documentation is wrong? Am I wrong ? How should I decrypt the assertion if its encrypted with his private key ?

There is a post with the same doubt: http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2016-June/006668.html

Thx

Answer (score 0):

You are quoting the text from the manual of Keycloak for adding clients, which would be your SP for example.

As client/SP you can encrypt the symmetric key for the encryption of your request details with the public key of the realm.

The text in the manual is in fact wrong in this place and I cannot see really where it would be right. Maybe they meant:

> Encrypt assertions in SAML documents **to be decrypted** with the
>   realm’s private key. The AES algorithm is used with a key size of 128
>   bits. The AES algorithm [...]

There is something odd about the statement with regard to AES also. It seems they are saying the client is restricted to ONLY use 128 bit keys, which would be strange. Almost as if they copied this from a server section, that I cannot find.

As a client, if you use encryption in your SAML messages you should encrypt the symmetric key with the public key of the IdP.

Comment: And if the IdP wants to send the assertions encrypted they should use the SP public key, correct?

Comment: Yes. Because it is then meant for the SP only, and only the SP has its private key to decrypt the message sent by the IdP.